# Need an element's parent index using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three `<ul>`s that expand when their buttons are clicked.  Not all three `<ul>`s will show up - only when there is a notification to show.  I hard-coded the values for now, but I can instantiate them on an as-needed basis.

Right now, they cover each other when they expand.  I would like the others to move when a list is expanded so they don't cover each other. I was thinking of getting the index of the one whose button is clicked and then resetting the bottom style of the others. I need to get the index of the `<ul>` parent of the button that was clicked, probably using jQuery but straight JavaScript is fine as well. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="NotificationDiv">
  <ul id="noticeLead" class="notification_base notification_Lead"><button id="notification_button">Lead Notice</button>
    <div>
        <li id="urlLead" class="notification_urlNotice notification_notice">
            <a  target="_blank" >Check Lead #1</a>
        </li>
        <li id="urlLead" class="notification_urlNotice notification_notice">
            <a  target="_blank" >Check Lead #2</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>

<ul id="noticeTask" class="notification_base notification_Task"><button id="notification_button">Task Notice</button>
    <div>
        <li id="urlTask" class="notification_urlNotice notification_notice">
            <a  target="_blank" >Check Task #5</a>    
        </li>
        <li id="urlTask" class="notification_urlNotice notification_notice">
            <a  target="_blank" >Check Task #6</a>
        </li>
    <div>
</ul>

<ul id="noticePolicy" class="notification_base notification_Policy"><button id="notification_button">Policy Notice</button>
    <div>
        <li id="urlPolicy" class="notification_urlNotice notification_notice">
            <a  target="_blank" >Check Policy #3</a>
        </li>
        <li id="urlPolicy" class="notification_urlNotice notification_notice">
            <a  target="_blank" >Check Policy #4</a>
        </li>
    </div>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And in the `$(document).ready`, I have:

```
$('.notification_base').on('click', 'button', function(){
    $(this).closest('.notification_base').find('.notification_urlNotice').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Not sure I understood what you want, but you should look into https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Your markup is invalid. A div is not an allowed child of a UL element.

Comment: And a button is not valid child either.

Comment: Can you post your CSS as well because slideToggle() shouldn't make them cover each other when they open.

Comment: It seems to work fine. What's the question? https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2wtdc70j/

Comment: Chris-Spittles, how can I post the CSS?  I've never posted in stackoverflow before.

Comment: @npayne you can post your CSS the same way you have done with your HTML and CSS. You could create it as a snippet so we can actually see your code working or not. Here's an article on how to do it: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your input.  I changed my structure to a table assigning .parent class to the header row and .child class to the data row and put this code in the jQuery ready function and it works great.

```
function getChildren($row) {
  var children = [];
  while($row.next().hasClass('child')) {
    children.push($row.next());
    $row = $row.next();
  }            
  return children;
}        

$('.parent').on('click', function() {
  var children = getChildren($(this));
  $.each(children, function() {
    $(this).toggle();
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myParentId; //Here you'll store the id of the clicked element
$('.notification_base').on('click', 'button', function(){
    $(this).closest('.notification_base').find('.notification_urlNotice').slideToggle();
    myParentId = $(this).attr("id");
});
```